# How to avoid negation while using hyphen?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a query that looks similar to:

```
db.mycollection.find({
     $text: {
        $search: "my -city"
     }
})
```

If I run this query, it will negate `city`. But I want to search for the exact phrase `my -city`. How can I do this?

The text to search could be `my-city` or `my - city` or `my -city`. Is there a way I can instruct mongodb to not use negation as the default behavior and just use the exact string matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping it in \" ... \" like this

```
db.mycollection.find({
     $text: {
        $search: "\"my -city\""
     }
})
```